# Getting error for import data from sheet in appmaker

Tags: google-app-maker

I am totally new to Appmaker. I just tried to import data from a sheet, however, I get the error in the picture and struggling to solve it for hours.
Any help or ideas appreciated.

[error that ocurred](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zowP5.png)

Comment: It looks like a bug, feel free to report it here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=192783&template=833410

Comment: It is a bug indeed. If you try to export data the samething happens.

Comment: Any idea how to fix it?